# Shallow copy of list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that [:] doing is shallow copy(member is not copied) ,still can someone explain this behaviour:

```
>>> a=[['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'],
...                        ['c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b'],
...                        ['b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a']
...                        ]
>>> for i in a:
...     i=i[4:]
... 
>>> a
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'], ['b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']]
>>>
```

why a is still not changed?
Sorry for noob question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify values of a list while iterating over it in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406449/modify-values-of-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say

```
i=i[4:]
```

you are not actually altering `i` to `i[4:]`, you are simply making `i` point to `i[4:]`. `i` is merely a reference to the actual list. In order to really change the data,

```
i[:]=i[4:]
```

Comment: Nice answer. Before reading this, I thought it has to be `for i in xrange(a): a[i] = a[i][4:]`.