# Updating Class Instance Attributes via SuperClass update() method

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm in the midst of coding a simulation for studying UAV interaction in swarms and obstacle avoidance scenarios. The issue I'm having currently is in getting the vehicles to update their positions. Basically, I have a base class which contains the update() method which does the calculation to arrive at the new position and velocity. The actual objects in the sim code are instances of a subclass of this, and in the subclass's update() method, all I do is update the acceleration vector and call super().update(). However, the values are retained after the function call. I assume this is just a lack of knowledge of Python on my part, as I'm just starting with it (coming from C++ for many years). The searches I've done for pass by reference and such are giving me good information, but so far I can't get an answer to this specific problem. Here's the code:

[EDIT] Per jonrsharpe's request, I've written out a minimal example that encapsulates the problem I'm having. Here's the minimal code:

```
class UpdateTester:
    x = [0,0]

    def update(self):
        for elem in self.x:
            elem += 1

class SubClassTester(UpdateTester):
    def update(self):
        super(SubClassTester,self).update()


a = SubClassTester()

for i in range(1,5):
    a.update()
    print(a.x)
```

So basically, per my(admittedly limited) understanding, I should get an output which shows increments to the list a.x. However, my output from running this example shows repeated [0,0]'s as output.

Comment: I should add that I track the position of the objects by printing each state vector, which are initialized to [0,0]. Through the whole simulation run, the states never change from that, which is how I know the values aren't being updated for each instance.

Comment: Could you cut and add where necessary to convert this to a complete [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with input data, so we can recreate the issue?

Comment: Certainly, give me a few minutes to put it together :)

Comment: Output from my interpreter:

[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
The thread 'MainThread' (0x1c49c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[97620] python.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: `elem += 1` **does not** change `x` (which is a *class attribute*, by the way); see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14406449/3001761

Comment: The enumerate solution given in that post is working for the minimal example. I don't understand comprehensions enough to try implementing his comprehensions based solution yet, so I'll work on that and update when I have results there.

Comment: For now, I'm using enumerate in my simulation program and it's working fine. Comprehensions for lists are going to take me a while to get, but I wanted to post here that the problem has been solved, at least for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers are immutable in Python therefore `for elem in self.x: elem += 1` does *nothing*. It doesn't change `self.x`. If you want to change `self.x`:

```
for i, value in enumerate(self.x):
    self.x[i] = value + 1
```

Also `UpdateTester.x` is a class variable. It is the same for all instances. Lists are mutable in Python therefore if you call `.update()` on any instance of `UpdateTester` class then you change the list for all of them. To create per instance list instead, put it in `__init__()`:

```
class UpdateTester(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateTester, self).__init__(**kwargs) # for multiple inheritence
        self.x = []
```