# Confused by list behavior of python

Tags: python, string

Iam a novice in Python .Python list cannot be amended in a loop . The output for this is unchanged array str1. Iam trying to make this list zero.This is a little strange for me .
Why cant I change the elements of the list ?

```
 import re,string
 str1=["This is a review","This is not a review"]
 for each in str1:
    each=" "
 print str1
```

Any clue?

Comment: In python List is type of object 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292174/are-python-lists-mutable

Comment: @Kasra, I would think this is more a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406449/modify-values-of-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python

Comment: @krock doesn't make much difference! questions like this have a lot of dup! :)

Comment: Guys we should use machine learning to better autosuggest similar topics . Semantic similarity and such . Just my two cents .

Answer (score 4):

Here you are changing the local variable `each` and not the elements in the list.  You can access the list by using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the indexes:

```
for idx, each in enumerate(str1):
    str1[idx] = " "
```

Comment: Thanks .I shdve known this .:)

Answer (score 0):

list are immutable. you cannot destroy the lest if thats what your trying to get at.

Comment: no, lists are mutable.